# Display simple public user profile for all registered users (not just authors)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In [a simple WordPress plugin](https://github.com/afarber/wp-newbie/blob/master/wp-city-gender/wp-city-gender.php) I have redirected commenter links to the URL `/user/user_id` with the following code:

```
define('PROFILE', '<a href="/user/%d">%s</a>');

function my_get_comment_author_link($comment_ID) {
    global $comment;
    return sprintf(PROFILE, $comment->user_id, 
                            $comment->comment_author);
}

add_action('get_comment_author_link',
           'my_get_comment_author_link');
```

How could I please show a simple public user profile (for all registered users and not just authors) displaying the user name at that URL?

I guess I should create a PHP script in my child 2013 theme -

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Public User Profile */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      // somehow get the user ID out of URL?
      // somehow get the WP_User object?
      printf('<p>Name: %s</p>', $user->display_name);
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But how to make the WordPress to execute that PHP script, when the URL `/user/user_id` is reuqested?

Should I use the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) here and how? I have tried the following, but don't see any effect:

```
                    add_rewrite_rule('/user/(\d+)',
                                     'index.php?XXX=$matches[1]',
                                     'top'
                    );
                    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Or am I missing something, like maybe I should add a custom post type first? (As you see - I am confused and "lost in the docs").

**UPDATE:**

Can I maybe override `the_content` hook - but how to detect that a `/user/user_id` page has been called?

```
function my_content($content)
{
    if (NOT /user/user_id CALLED)
        return $content;

    // otherwise somehow extract the user_id
    // somehow get the corresponding WP_User
    return sprintf('<p>Name: %s</p>', $user->display_name);
}

add_action('the_content', 'my_content');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some (hopefully helpful) remarks:

- Avoid putting everything into a giant super class, keep your classes as small and focused (task oriented) as possible. [Auto loading classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) can also be handy.
- Keep your [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) within the [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook, because you don't want to loose the rewrite when you visit the permalink settings page and re-save the permalinks:

  ```
  public static function init()
  {
      // ... your code  ...

      add_rewrite_rule(
          'user/([^/]*)/?',
          'index.php?wpcg_user=$matches[1]',
          'top'
      );              
  }
  ```

  Notice the `/?` part, to account for both `user/123` and `user/123/`. The `add_rewrite_rule()` call will not flush the rewrite rules automatically.
- Another way is to register an endpoint with [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) :

  ```
  public static function init()
  {
      // ... your code  ...

      add_rewrite_endpoint( 'user', EP_ALL );
  }
  ```

  where you can modify the places where it will be accessible: `EP_ALL`, `EP_PAGES`, `EP_PERMALINK`, `...` . Notice that it will create a new rewrite rule where `/user/123/` is mapped to `?user=123`.
- You can use the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action or [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter to modify what template you want to display.
- You should register your custom GET variable, `wpcg_user`, with the [`query_vars`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) filter, for example:

  ```
  public static function query_vars( $vars )
  {
      $vars[] = 'wpcg_user';
      return $vars;
  }
  ```

  so you can retrieve it later with [`get_query_var( 'wpcg_user' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).
- When `get_query_var( 'wpcg_user')` is non-empty, you know that the requested url is like  `http://example.com/user/123/`.
- You should allow the WordPress admin to override the default plugin template, `tpl-user.php`, by copying it into the current theme directory.  The function [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) can help you with that:

  ```
  if ( '' != locate_template( 'tpl-user.php') )
  ```
- Your `template_redirect` method, if you choose to use the corresponding hook, could then look like this:

  ```
  public static function template_redirect()
  {
      $wpcg_user = get_query_var( 'wpcg_user' );

      $tpl = 'tpl-user.php';  // Your custom template file.

      if( ! empty( $wpcg_user ) )
      {
          if ( '' == locate_template( $tpl, TRUE ) )
              include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $tpl );  

          exit();
      }
  }
  ```

  where you might have to adjust the path to your `tpl-user.php` template, for example if you keep it in a sub-directory within your `wp-city-gender` plugin directory. Notice that we use the second input argument of the `locate_template()` function, so it will load the template if it can find it.
- Your `tpl-user.php` template file could look like this:

  ```
  <?php
   /* Template Name: Public User Profile */
   ?>

  <?php get_header(); ?>

  <div>
  <?php 
  // Get the user query:
  $wpcg_user = get_query_var( 'wpcg_user' );  

  // Get corresponding user by id:
  $user = get_user_by( 'id', absint( $wpcg_user ) );

  if( $user ):
      printf('<p> Name: %s </p>',   $user->display_name                      );
      printf('<p> City: %s </p>',   get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'city',   TRUE));
      printf('<p> Gender: %s </p>', get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'gender', TRUE));
  else:
      _e( 'Sorry, no user found!' );
  endif;
  ?>
  </div>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
  ```

  where we use the [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) function, to retrieve the corresponding user data.
- We could easily have used the user *slug* instead of the user *id*, by using `get_user_by( 'slug', $wpcg_user );` instead of `get_user_by( 'id', absint( $wpcg_user ) );`.
- You need the following, in your current setup:

  ```
  add_action( 'template_redirect',  array( CNAME, 'template_redirect') );
  add_filter( 'query_vars',         array( CNAME, 'query_vars') );
  //add_action( 'template_include', array( CNAME, 'template_include') );
  ```

  activate the corresponding hook callbacks.
- There are many tools available to help you with custom rewrites, for example the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/). It has not been updated in a while, but still works great.

  Here's a screenshot showing the `/user/1/` inspection, with the above rewrite:

  [image: wpcg_user inspection]

  I hope this helps. Just let me know if you need help implementing this. I tested these modifications on my install and it worked there.

**Update:**

*In response to a comment:*

How to handle the case where the template is located in a sub-directory, for example `/templates/profile.php`?

We can use the following:

```
if ( '' == locate_template( 'templates/profile.php', TRUE ) )
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/profile.php' );
```

This means:

- If `/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/templates/profile.php` is located, then it will be automatically loaded.
- Else: `/wp-content/plugins/wp-city-gender/templates/profile.php` is loaded.

where we assume that `__FILE__`  is in the `wp-city-gender` root directory.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this works - I have updated GitHub. Two more questions, please: 1. Why do you call the `get_template_part('tpl', 'user')`, when the template is not found? 2. How to include jQuery and CSS code of DataTables-plugin just in my template page, but not in the rest pages of my website?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderFarber thanks. Glad to hear it worked for you. 1. I call the `get_template_part()` when  `locate_template()` is non empty, otherwise I include the template that's shipped with the plugin. 2. You can, for example, add a condition inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, where you check if `get_query_var( 'wpcg_user' )` is non empty, else you don't enqueue your custom style/script. I Hope this is answers these two questions. If not I can try to construct an example.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, but I have named my template file `templates/profile.php` (and not `tpl-user.php` as suggested by you). If you look at the code near `get_template_part` in my plugin, do I call it wrong? https://github.com/afarber/wp-newbie/blob/master/wp-city-gender/wp-city-gender.php

Comment: There's no such thing as a stupid question. I will add a code example to the answer, on how to handle sub-directories.

Comment: ps: you dont' need both  `add_rewrite_endpoint ` and  `add_rewrite_rule` and you could perhaps include your admin forms from a file to simplify things.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more about the `get_template_part('tpl', 'user')` call: since it will look for `tpl-user.php`, how to call that method for my `templates/profile.php`? Because I don't have a hyphen "-" in my file name anymore. So should I maybe call `get_template_part('', 'templates/profile')`?

Comment: yes, using `get_template_part( 'templates/profile' )` should work.

Answer (score 1):

How about you check the page template instead of the url??

if ( is_page_template('public_profile.php') ) {
    // code to execute when the pages using the Template of public_profile.php file(Your Public User Profile Template file) are loaded.
}

Have a look at this function [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

Or you can also get the template used by the current page to check the template.
See [get_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template)

Comment: +1 Thanks, but where should I put the check `is_page_template`? In the main `index.php` of WordPress? I don't really understand how your suggestion works.

Comment: I would suggest you to write it in your function.php file

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress shows **every** (whether an author, subscriber, or anything else) user's details at a page www.example.com/author/[USER NAME] , so you must just redirect to this URL-

```
www.example.com/author/<?php echo $comment->comment_author;?>
```

And, for editing the format of the details page, you should edit the author.php of your theme.

Comment: +1 thanks, but you probably mean `example.com/archives/author/[USER_NAME]`? At my website I can see http://slova.de/archives/author/afarber (an Author user) and http://slova.de/archives/author/Cake (a Contributor user, the page shows "Nothing Found" though)...

Comment: Hey, no I actually mean www.example.com/author/[USER NAME], because on my server it shows me the author's info page, which is generated through author.php in my theme's directory.

Comment: Oh, so it's maybe theme-dependend? I am using the stock 2013 theme

Comment: You can check that by seeing whether your theme contains author.php